# How can I use .collect(Collectors.joining) to convert Map into String

Tags: java

I have my method that should return String with values from a map.
But the problem is that the output of the code below is

> Some Word Example

Instead of

> Some - 2, Word - 6, Example - 4

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<String, Integer> myMap = new HashMap<>();
        myMap.put("Some", 2);
        myMap.put("Example", 4);
        myMap.put("Word", 6);

        System.out.println(countWords(myMap));
    }

        public static String countWords(Map<String, Integer> stringIntegerHashMap) {
        String result = stringIntegerHashMap.entrySet().stream()
                .map(e -> e.getKey())
                .collect(Collectors.joining("\r\n"));
        return result;
    }
```

Comment: If you only need the keys, use the `keySet()` instead of the `entrySet()`.

Comment: @Turing85 I need to use both, the output should be a String of 'MapKey- MapValue' pairs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`Collectors.joining(...)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#joining(java.lang.CharSequence)) is only responsible to join the `Stream`-elements with a delimiter. In the given case, however, we have to first map the `Stream`-emements, i.e. the `Map.Entry`s, in "the correct format", i.e. `"<key> - <value>"`. For this, we modify the function used by `Stream::map`:

```
public static String countWords(Map<String, Integer> stringIntegerHashMap) {
  return stringIntegerHashMap.entrySet().stream()
      .map(entry -> entry.getKey() +  " - " + entry.getValue())
      .collect(Collectors.joining("\r\n"));
}
```

[<kbd>Ideone demo</kbd>](https://ideone.com/K5En0H)

Answer (score 0):

For now in `map` you keep only the key, you need to concatenate the key with the value

```
public static String countWords(Map<String, Integer> stringIntegerHashMap) {
    return stringIntegerHashMap.entrySet().stream()
            .map(e -> e.getKey() + " - " + e.getValue())
            .collect(Collectors.joining("\r\n"));
}
```

```
Some-2
Word-6
Example-4
```

Comment: Minor nitpick: the sample-output is missing some blanks :)